# onActivityResult() not called after taking a photo

Tags: android, onactivityresult

I have used this code for take photo from camera however `onActivityResult()` not call.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
File f = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"temp.jpg");
intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

Comment: Are you implementing the onActivityResult method?

Comment: Similar question/answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21421419/onactivityresult-not-called-after-taking-a-photo-in-android

Answer (score 0):

you don't have `onActivityResult()` method, check this related problem [onActivityResult error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13987362/onactivityresult-error) . OP had almost working example.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to take a photo :

1 - Using an Intent to make a photo

2 - Using the camera API

I think you should use the second way and there is [a sample code](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidCamera/article.html) for two of them.

Hope It helps.